# Given an author name, display tid value from the given twitter dataset

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher

Given below a sample of twitter dataset from which I have to retreive tid data of given author.

```
{
    "934934507945312256": {
    "quote_count": 0,
    "reply_count": 0,
    "hashtags": null,
    "datetime": "2017-11-26 23:58:51",
    "date": "2017-11-26",
    "like_count": 0,
    "verified": "False",
    "sentiment": 0,
    "author": "JudyThe Resistance",
    "location": "Hollywood, California USA",
    "tid": "934934507945312256",
    "retweet_count": 0,
    "type": "retweet",
    "media_list": null,
    "quoted_source_id": null,
    "url_list": null,
    "tweet_text": "RT @kylegriffin1: Reminder: The Senate Judiciary Committee gave Jared Kushner a November 27 deadline to turn over the missing records… ",
    "author_profile_image": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profi...",
    "author_screen_name": "jgirl66",
    "author_id": "23737528",
    "lang": "en",
    "keywords_processed_list": [
    "reminder",
    "senate judiciary committee",
    "kushner november",
    "deadline"
    ],
    "retweet_source_id": "934872065471115264",
    "mentions": [
    "kylegriffin1"
    ],
    "replyto_source_id": null
    },
    "934934503604174848": {
    "quote_count": 0,
    "reply_count": 2,
    "hashtags": [
    "MissUniverse",
    "Thailand"
    ],
    "datetime": "2017-11-26 23:58:50",
    "date": "2017-11-26",
    "like_count": 38,
    "verified": "False",
    "sentiment": 0,
    "author": "P'Hmee7.5",
    "location": "Bangkok, Thailand",
    "tid": "934934503604174848",
    "retweet_count": 105,
    "type": "Tweet",
    "media_list": null,
    "quoted_source_id": null,
    "url_list": null,
    "tweet_text": "รอโหวต มรญ #MissUniverse #Thailand",
    "author_profile_image": "
    Thumbnail
    ",
    "author_screen_name": "Peehmee75",
    "author_id": "700720806972624897",
    "lang": "th",
    "keywords_processed_list": null,
    "retweet_source_id": null,
    "mentions": null,
    "replyto_source_id": null
    },
    "934934336381636608": {
    "quote_count": 0,
    "reply_count": 0,
    "hashtags": null,
    "datetime": "2017-11-26 23:58:10",
    "date": "2017-11-26",
    "like_count": 0,
    "verified": "False",
    "sentiment": 0,
    "author": "selfresqingprncess",
    "location": "Maine, USA",
    "tid": "934934336381636608",
    "retweet_count": 0,
    "type": "retweet",
    "media_list": null,
    "quoted_source_id": null,
    "url_list": null,
    "tweet_text": "RT @kylegriffin1: Reminder: The Senate Judiciary Committee gave Jared Kushner a November 27 deadline to turn over the missing records… ",
    "author_profile_image": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profi...",
    "author_screen_name": "slfresqngprncss",
    "author_id": "100536014",
    "lang": "en",
    "keywords_processed_list": [
    "reminder",
"keywords_processed_list": [
            "reminder",
            "senate judiciary committee",
            "kushner november",
            "deadline"
        ],
        "retweet_source_id": "934872065471115264",
        "mentions": [
            "kylegriffin1"
        ],
        "replyto_source_id": null
    },
  }
```

Till now I have made a graph containing all tweet information of different author.

```
    json = json.load(data_file)
    query = """
    WITH {json} AS data
    UNWIND KEYS($json) AS k
    MERGE(label:author{name:$json[k].author,date_time:$json[k].datetime,tid:$json[k].tid,tweettext:$json[k].tweet_text,authorid:$json[k].author_id,location:$json[k].location,language:$json[k].lang})
    """
    graph.run(query,json=json)
```

Now I want the **tid value** of author with name **JudyThe Resistance**.

```
MATCH (n) WHERE n.name='JudyThe Resistance' RETURN n.tid
```

This query is providing me tid value in table section in neo4j localserver but unable to fetch the tid value in my python script.

```
import json
json = json.load(data_file)
query =""" MATCH (n) WHERE n.name='JudyThe Resistance' RETURN n.tid """
val=graph.run(query,json=json)
```

This **val** is providing me no tid data.

Comment: Show, in your question, the Python script.

Comment: Also, why is the `name` property of `author` nodes being used to hold 6 different kinds of values? Seems like you need to improve your data model. Perhaps you need 6 different labels (with `author` being just one of them), at the very least?

Comment: A valid SO question asks about a specific problem you encountered while writing a program yourself; dumping a specification and expecting us to write your program for you is "too broad". See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) on [meta].

Answer (score 0):

```
query = "MATCH (n) WHERE n.name='JudyThe Resistance' RETURN n.tid as TID"
val = tx.run(query)
print val.single()[0]
```

or

```
query = "MATCH (n) WHERE n.name='JudyThe Resistance' RETURN n.tid as TID"
val = tx.run(query)
print val.single()["TID"]
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'single'

Comment: This is working:-                                                             
  graph.run(query,json=json)
 for record in graph.run("MATCH (n) WHERE n.name='selfresqingprncess' RETURN n ORDER BY n.date_time DESC"):
       print(record["n"]["tid"])